# Use Power Automate to Send Email with Link to Created Item in Datasheet View

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have created a SharePoint list to automate and track PO requests. Once the request has been approved, I have a Power Automate flow that sends an email to the team so they can create the PO as well as a confirmation email to the requestor. In the confirmation email I have a link that takes them directly to their form so they can modify if necessary. In SharePoint, I have a Datasheet view that has 3 fields (columns) the PO creator needs to update once they have created the PO. These fields are not visible in the form. I have inserted the URL to the Datasheet view as well as the ID of the item in the email. It will go to the Datasheet view but I cannot seem to get it to go to the specific record that needs updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For refering to Item via URL you can choose:

**1) Filtered View**

Use  `?FilterField1=ID&FilterValue1=2` query string URL to filter item with ID = 2.
(IMPORTANT NOTE: "ID" column must be visible in the view, otherwise it will not work, maybe thats the issue you are experiencing.)

**Example:**

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Site123/Lists/CustomList/AllItems.aspx?FilterField1=ID&FilterValue1=2`

**2) Direct link to the Edit form**

For link directly to edit form of item ID = 2 use this URL parameter `/EditForm.aspx?ID=2` or `/DispForm.aspx?ID=2` for Display form.

**Example:**

`https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Site123/Lists/CustomList/EditForm.aspx?ID=2`

You can refer to Microsoft Learn article for more tricks here:
[Query String URL Tricks for SharePoint and Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/query-string-url-tricks-sharepoint-m365)

Comment: Popkornak,

Thank you so much for your help. I did have the ID field visible but the FilterField and FilterValue solved my problem.